# approve spender and migration is not working what i am doing wrong?

Tags: java, web, solidity

below is my code i am working on a migration project, user connected to the website when clicks on  migrate button should send the request for spender approval and then send all the token to the smart contract to receive the new one however doesn't seem to be working.

```
const contractProcessor = useWeb3ExecuteFunction ();

async function migration() {
    let options = {
contractAddress:"0x38401323a55ADB644429aF88E3e7705d2bD51a08",
functionName:"MigrateToV2",
abi:[{"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"addr","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"MigrateToV2","type":"event"}],
params:{
max_amount,
  note:"Migration completed!"
 }
 }
 await contractProcessor.fetch({ 
 params: options
})
}
const ethers = require('ethers');

const WENLAMBOInterface = ['function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)'];
const WENLAMBOAddress = '0xB1485622Ca84eAc032D9943ce4A0B7867a48614c';
const yourContractAddress = "0x38401323a55ADB644429aF88E3e7705d2bD51a08";

let provider;
let signer;
let signerAddress;
let WENLAMBOContract;

const startFunction = async () => {
   await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
   await ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params:[{chainId: '0x61'}]});
   provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
   signer = provider.getSigner();
   signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();
   USDTContract = await new ethers.Contract(WENLAMBOAddress, WENLAMBOInterface, signer);
}
startFunction();

async function approveWENLAMBO(){
   WENLAMBOContract.approve(yourContractAddress, BigInt("9007199254740990")**3n);
}
//Whenever this function is called, a transaction request is sent to user's metamask and whenever
//user confirms it, it is approved!

    </Card>
    <center><Button onClick={() => approveWENLAMBO && migration()}>Click to migrate </Button></center>
   </div>
</div>
);
 }
```

as you can see on click has been defined but the function is not executed when  i click

Comment: functionName: migrateToV2 was changed for MigrateToV2 as per ABI but still not working

Comment: That is too much code to be easily analyzed for your question to be answered.  Can you reduce the amount to make it a [mre] please.